# It is possible to run cron job in subdomain?

Tags: codeigniter, cron

It is possible to run cron job in subdomain?

we are using codeigniter framework. It is working fine in our main domain "physioplustech.com"
But it is not working in sub domain  "rehab.physioplustech.com"

Our subdomain : rehab.physioplustech.com

scripting file is : rehab.physioplustech.com/client/feesupdate/updatefees

Comment: I'm confused by the wording of your question.  Does CodeIgniter not work on your subdomain, or just your cron job?

Comment: Can you access the URL through your browser?